# Adding a Product to the Cart via Querystring using SKU

Tags: addtocart, query, sku

I know that we can [adding a product to cart via querystring](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring#adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring).
but how do we add sku to cart via querystring in url without including **product id**
like this : 
domain/checkout/cart/add?sku=ABC 
or 
domain/checkout/cart/add/sku=BC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andhi Irawan,you can not do this type of work at `checkout Cart controllers`. If want this type of work then you need to `rewrite Checkout CartController.php` and on this class magento is `load the product object  by id` before `going to cart`,So you need `load product by sku on` this place .

**Step 1**: rewrite cartController.php  and code is for xml rewrite

```
   <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <customcart before="Mage_Checkout">YourNameSpace_YourMOdule</customcart>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
```

**Step2:** and on your extended `Cartcontorller` `_initProduct` function you need product load product by sku

```
     protected function _initProduct()
  {
    $sku=$this->getRequest()->setParam('sku');
    $_catalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $idBySku = $_catalog->getIdBySku($sku);

    if ($idBySku) { 
        $productId = $idBySku;
    $this->getRequest()->setParam('product', $productId );
    }else{
    $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
    }
    if ($productId) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->load($productId);
        if ($product->getId()) {
        return $product;
        }
    }

        return false;
    }
```

How to rewrite controller see more at : http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento/

Comment: Amit Bera, thank you for your help. i had read your tutorial how to override controller. previous checkout module is apparently already override on the path code\local\ABC\Checkout\. so I do not change the file config.xml. I added a function _initProduct in code\local\ABC\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php.The following config.xml file contents:<br/><?xml version="1.0" ?><config><frontend><routers><checkout><args><modules><abc_checkout before="Mage_Checkout">ABC_Checkout</abc_checkout></modules></args></checkout></routers></frontend></config>

Comment: my app\code\local\ABC\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php : http://pastebin.com/873rBFYm

Comment: On  magenot 1.9   magent is used form key which is validate your cart is proper or not  if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }

Comment: hey,is it resolved or not

Comment: hi Amit Bera, sorry I was sick yesterday. my Magento version 1.7. and yes, it resolved. thanks to you and the tutorial you made. i modify the config.xml, function _initProduct() in CartController.php and adding a helper file app\code\local\ABC\Checkout\Helper\Cart.php

Answer (score 1):

my function _initProduct() : pastebin.com/873rBFYm

```
protected function _initProduct()
{
    $sku = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sku'); 
    $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');

    if($sku){
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $productId = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getProductIdByParams($params, false);
        if(! $productId){
            return false;
        }
    }

    if ($productId) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($productId);
        if ($product->getId()) {
            return $product;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

my config.xml : pastebin.com/Ks85etyQ

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><config>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <abc_checkout before="Mage_Checkout">ABC_Checkout</abc_checkout>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend><global><helpers>
    <checkout>
        <rewrite>
            <cart>ABC_Checkout_Helper_Cart</cart>
        </rewrite>
    </checkout>
</helpers></global></config>
```

my helper : app\code\local\ABC\Checkout\Helper\Cart.php : pastebin.com/RZGSKJdr

```
<?php class ABC_Checkout_Helper_Cart extends Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart{
public function getProductIdByParams($param, $outputFlag = true){
    $sku = trim($param['sku']);
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                                                 ->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

    if($_product){
        $productTypeId = $_product->getTypeId();
        $productId = $_product->getId();
        if($productTypeId == 'simple'){
            $result = $outputFlag ? true : $productId;
        }
        elseif($productTypeId == 'configurable'){
            $color = trim($param['color']);
            $size = trim($param['size']);
            $config = trim($param['option']);

            $configurableProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
            $simpleCollections = $configurableProduct->getUsedProductCollection()
                                                     ->addAttributeToSelect('id');
            if(! empty($color)){
                $attrColor = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute("sp_color");
                $colorId = $attrColor->usesSource() ? $attrColor->getSource()->getOptionId($color) : '';
                $simpleCollections->addAttributeToFilter('sp_color', $colorId);
            }
            if(! empty($size)){
                $attrSize = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute("sp_size");
                $sizeId = $attrSize->usesSource() ? $attrSize->getSource()->getOptionId($size) : '';
                $simpleCollections->addAttributeToFilter('sp_size', $sizeId);
            }
            if(! empty($config)){
                $attrConfig = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute("sp_config");
                $configId = $attrConfig->usesSource() ? $attrConfig->getSource()->getOptionId($config) : '';
                $simpleCollections->addAttributeToFilter('sp_config', $configId);
            }
            $simpleCollections->addFilterByRequiredOptions();                                         

            if($simpleCollections->count() == 1){
                $productId = $simpleCollections->getFirstItem()->getId();
                $result = $outputFlag ? true : $productId;
            }
            else{
                $result = false;
            }

        }
        return $result;
    }
    return false;
}}
```

so sku can be adding via url querystring like this :

SIMPLE PRODUCT

```
Parameter:<br/>
~ sku<br/>
~ qty<br/>
```

a. Add product with qty = 1

```
domain/id/index.php/checkout/cart/add/sku/ABCD<br/>
or<br/>
domain/id/index.php/checkout/cart/add?sku=ABCD
```

b. Add product with qty more than 1

```
domain/id/index.php/checkout/cart/add/sku/ABCD/qty/3<br/>
or<br/>
domain/id/index.php/checkout/cart/add?sku=ABCD&qty=3<br/>

CONFIGURABLE PRODUCT<br/>
Parameter:<br/>
~ sku<br/>
~ color<br/>
~ size<br/>
~ option (ex: used by XYZ)<br/>
~ qty<br/>
~ __store (id or en)<br/>
```

a. Add product with qty = 1

```
domain/id/index.php/checkout/cart/add/sku/XYZ/color/merah tua/size/M/__store/id<br/>
domain/id/index.php/checkout/cart/add/sku/XYZ/color/maroon/size/M/__store/en<br/>
domain/id/index.php/checkout/cart/add/sku/XYZ/option/bilqis/__store/id<br/>
or<br/>
domain/id/index.php/checkout/cart/add?sku=XYZ&color=merah tua&size=M&__store=id<br/>
domain/id/index.php/checkout/cart/add?sku=XYZ&color=maroon&size=M&__store=en<br/>
domain/id/index.php/checkout/cart/add?sku=XYZ&option=bilqis&__store=id<br/>
```

b. Add product with qty more than 1

```
domain/id/index.php/checkout/cart/add/sku/XYZ/color/merah tua/size/M/qty/3/__store/id<br/>
domain/id/index.php/checkout/cart/add/sku/XYZ/color/maroon/size/M/qty/3/__store/en<br/>
domain/id/index.php/checkout/cart/add/sku/XYZ/option/bilqis/qty/3/__store/id<br/>
or<br/>
domain/id/index.php/checkout/cart/add?sku=XYZ&color=merah tua&size=M&qty=3&__store=id<br/>
domain/id/index.php/checkout/cart/add?sku=XYZ&color=maroon&size=M&qty=3&__store=en<br/>
domain/id/index.php/checkout/cart/add?sku=XYZ&option=bilqis&qty=3&__store=id
```